# javascript regex search from end of string to begining

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to use regex to search from end of string to beginning?

for example i have a string: "a2bba2b"

I know i need the last occurrence of /a2/ and it seems highly inefficient to make machine go trough whole string which can be quite long. I know the needle will  be somewhere near the end of string(haystack), so i would like to reverse the order simply tell the script to search from end to beginning to save some resources. 
Regex seems like a way to go match more complicated string.And it is way easier to write complex regex than your own search function.

So is there a way maybe a flag or something to reverse searching order to match regex from end to start of input string. Does any of the modern languages support something like that? if not why?

Comment: What do you mean by "i need the last occurrence of /a2/"? What is expected valid and invalid match?

Comment: @guest271314 smth like .lastIndexOf() but written in regex executing regex method search()

Comment: Why is `RegExp` necessary if `.lastIndexOf()` returns expected result? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 save machine time by making it search from end since string to search is big and in most cases the needle is somewhere near end

Comment: Search for what? To return a `Boolean`; or, an index reflecting the position within the input string if the specific characters are matched? How do you know that searching from the opposite direction will "save machine time"?

Comment: to return a Boolean

Comment: You could convert string to an array, then use `Array.prototype.reduceRight()` or `.reverse()` to reverse string, though then we have introduced further function calls. What exactly is not returning expected result using current approach? It is not clear what issue is?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: tbh i am testing atm because i had no idea lastIndexOf takes regex as input. will post an answer if i find one

Comment: the issue is that input string that needs to be searched is very large and speed is crucial, so when i use regex to search, in most cases it could go fast if it could search from end to beginning.Because in most cases what i am searching for is close to the end of input string. Your proposed solution reverse is highly inefficient on big input string, not sure about reduceRight i am still testing that

if i could get either boolean that says it matches or index of string that matches that would be great.

Comment: _"speed is crucial"_ , _"go fast"_ , _"highly inefficient"_ What is benchmark for current approach? _"highly inefficient"_ compared to? Have you read previous comment?

Comment: i did ok lets say the input string is big 1 Terabayte and you know in most cases the needle is somewhere in last megabayte.

Comment: _"lets say"_ Is that a hypothetical scenario which cannot be practically reproduced by viewers of Question? You could read the data from reverse using `ReadableStream` - by first expending the resources to reverse a terabyte of data - though we still need to know what the current benchmark is, or else the inquiry truly is _"the needle is somewhere"_

Comment: look tbh it is the same thing if string is 20KB which is the case and you need to find match in 10ms on bad machine and you know it is somwhere near the end... see no reason for tensions

Comment: There are no "tensions", at least none here. This is direct communication. What is "bad machine"?

Comment: a win 10 4gb ram with 10 chrome tabs opened and some duo cores 4 years old processor, could as well be smth like first gen raspberry. How does that contribute to solution?

Comment: Neither contribute to solution because no clear problem statement appears at original Question, thus no solution is possibly viable at this point.

Comment: Yesterday would have simply voted to close the Question due to being unclear or lacking clear problem statement. However, that procedure has its own lack of clarity. More time consuming to engage in an apparently chase of the wild goose, though perhaps you have performed benchmarks, and we will be able to reproduce them.

Comment: seems pretty clear to me. a solid answer is no node doesn't support that thing "go" does or that is not possible because of inner workings of regex. there are many solid answers

Comment: Then you should post Answer to your own Question https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: i will if nobody responds in a day. i do it most of the time

Comment: I am still hoping this is not becoming a node or regex feature request

Comment: ps. seems quite obvious to me that there is no need for benchmarks, its just pure inefficiency in edge cases.
but to implement smth like that to support regex with reverse search would require a lot of work, so for concrete uses atm it seems the most efficient way to implement costume search algoritham written in js and ignore regex.

Comment: You found your needle

Comment: I found an inefficient haystack too , god lately it seems to me all i want to do is submit feature requests at js fucking v8 not supporting me the way i want it, gotta submit some pull request when i get time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JavaScript RegExp does not allow searching from the end of the string. The usual workaround is using a greedy dot matching pattern to make the engine grab the whole string and then backtrack to find the last occurrence (as [`/.*a\d/`](https://regex101.com/r/MvuSQl/1)), but it will become a pain if a large string does not really contain this pattern.

If the purpose is to *extract* the last match, you may get all matches and grab the last one (`s.match(/a\d/g).pop()` (well, there must be a null check, of course)).

There are regex engines that actually let you parse the string from right to left.

- .NET regex uses [`RegexOptions.RightToLeft` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.righttoleft?view=netframework-4.7) for this (see the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=a%5Cd&i=a2bba2b&o=r&s=7&l=1))
- In [Python PyPi regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/), you may also pass a `regex.R` (or inline `(?r)` version) to force a reverse matching: `regex.compile(r'a\d', regex.R).sub(r"**\g<0>**", "a2bba2b", count=1)` ==> `a2bb**a2**b`) (see [RexTester demo](http://rextester.com/DQGRBE89795)).

Answer (score 0):

How about string reverse your string and your regex? then get the first occurence?

Comment: that seems like a lot of machine time

Comment: There is no native "string reverse" method. The string would need to be converted to an array first, or a loop would need to be implemented.