# Regex - how to find match starting from end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

`"TEXT&nbsp;<p>TEST1</p><br><div>&nbsp;<p>TEST2</p></div>"`

(string, not html)

Here i am trying to capture the last `<p>` tag until `</p></div>`. (Edit: NOT just the text between, I'm including the actual string tags)

How do you start from the end from where `</p><div>` is to the next prior `<p>` that contains "TEST2" instead of "TEST1"? I am running into this problem because the first match (going forwards) contains the match I am looking for, rather than being a separate match.

I know I can grab the index of the `</p></div>` and then loop backwards until I find a `<p>`, but this seems inefficient. I also know RegEx in JavaScript does not allow you to do search from end of string based on this answer ([javascript regex search from end of string to begining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447818/javascript-regex-search-from-end-of-string-to-begining)) , so just posting because I am unaware of more optimal solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative look ahead:

[`<p>(?:.(?!<p>))+<\/div>`](https://regex101.com/r/9I1kAL/1)

Similar question: [Regex Last occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374742/regex-last-occurrence)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful resource!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var testStr='<p>TEST1</p><br><div>&nbsp;<p>TEST2</p></div>';
var matchesStr=testStr.match(/(\<[p]\>)(.|\;)*(\<\/p\>\<\/div\>){1}$/g);

// get your required result from array matchesStr 
console.log(matchesStr);

$('#matchResult').text(matchesStr.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="matchResult"></div>
```